# (main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, compilation

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Basically, I tried the following commands to compile my C++ code:

```
mkdir build
cd ./build
cmake-G "MinGW Makefiles"
make
```

When I compile the C++ library code for my model, I get this error.

[image]

**Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.**

Comment: The error is not about project's structure. It is about your **code**. Without viewing that code we cannot help you. See also [ask].

Comment: If you put `undefined reference to WinMain@16` into your favorite search engine, you should be getting plenty of hits.